# VBA passing a sub to another

Tags: vba, excel

have a general "wrap-around" code (error handling etc) that generally repeats through all subroutines:

```
Sub run1st()
    On Error GoTo Dammit
    Application.StatusBar = "Getting data from bla bla... "
    OptimizeVBA True

    'body of main code

continueProgress:
    Application.StatusBar = False
    OptimizeVBA False
    Call Dash
   Exit Sub
Dammit:
   MsgBox "Something's wrong: " & vbCrLf & Err.Description
   Resume continueProgress
   Resume
  End Sub
```

is there a way to pass 'main code' to this wrapper sub in arguments or some other clever way to avoid this clutter?

Comment: You could have `sub run1st(obj as IRunFirstable)` where `IRunFirstable` is an interface and `obj` is an instance of an implementing class that contains the code to run in a `RunCode` method.  You could then have as the body of code a single call to `obj.IRunFirstable_RunCode()`.

Comment: Whereas some languages (like C# and Java) have try catch finally  C++ does not have finally so they use RAII instead.  One can copy the RAII design pattern for VBA.  See this http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2016/09/use-raii-design-pattern-to-tidy-your.html